# JS Using array to show text after drop down selected

Tags: php, javascript, magento

Ok so I have some code that works perfectly for the first product I added into my store. But when I add the next product the drop down options auto increment the ID value in the selection. I need to find a way around this so it works on any product that is loaded.

Here is the Javascript:

```
    <script language="javascript">
   function displayCondition() {
     condition = new Array("Please Select a Condition.","<b>Perfect:</b> Text to explain perfect condition!", "<b>Excellent:</b> Text to explain excellent condition!", "<b>Good:</b> Text to explain good condition!", "<b>Poor:</b> Text to explain poor condition!", "<b>Broken:</b> Text to explain broken condition!");
     var getsel = document.getElementById('select_<?php echo $_option->getId();?>').value;
     document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = condition[getsel];
   }
</script>
```

Here is the working products code notice the IDs are 1-5:

```
    <select name="options[1]" id="select_1" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" 
title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();displayCondition()">
<option value="" >-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="1"  price="0" >Perfect </option>
<option value="2"  price="-35" >Excellent </option>
<option value="3"  price="-105" >Good </option>
<option value="4"  price="-140" >Poor </option>
<option value="5"  price="-252" >Broken </option>
</select>
```

And the code for the second product. Each product after this will keep incrementing:

```
   <select name="options[6]" id="select_6" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" 
title=""  onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();displayCondition();">
<option value="" >-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="13"  price="0" >Perfect </option>
<option value="14"  price="-35" >Excellent </option>
<option value="15"  price="-105" >Good </option>
<option value="16"  price="-140" >Poor </option>
<option value="17"  price="-252" >Broken </option>
</select>
```

The help I need is in the javascript. I can not change the values in the select's since they control the pricing that will affect each product. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Or if someone is familiar with Magento and can tell me where to add a the code to add a name="" field to the options I can fix it that way by creating my own autoincrement name field and use that to sort instead of the value field.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around what this actually is. Are you using custom options on a product? If you're using your own code, why don't you just start back at 1 for the other select?

Comment: This is in Magento. It is custom options that are set in the admin per product and assigned their own ID which is the value in the options.